# Как переписать этот метод с C++ на Python?

Tags: python, c++

Есть метод на C++

```
vector<unordered_set<int>> sortGraph(vector<vector<int>> &g, vector<int> &p) {
    vector<unordered_set<int>> answer;
    for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++)
        answer.push_back(unordered_set<int>());
    for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++)
        answer[p[i]].insert(i);
    return answer;
}
```

Правильно ли я переписал его на Python?

```
def sort_graph(g, p):
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(g)):
        answer.append(set())
    for i in range(len(g)):
        answer[p[i]].add(i)
    return answer
```

Еще почему-то во втором цикле в `add` `i` подчеркивается и IDE пишет `Expected type 'set' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'int' instead`

Comment: Да вроде всё правильно.

Comment: а самому протестировать, никак?